# Change a figure in a script depending on the width of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply have the following script, if you look after the `$('html,body').animate({` on line 9 you will see `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 95 }, 700);` - The question is, how would I change the figure **95** (it's after offset().top XX) When the screen width is under 1030px?

I tried to add this line of code and play around it, but it won't work - I don't know what I am doing wrong. `if (width <= 1030) {`

Here is the Script:

```
//Menu Scrolling To Sections//
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

    if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 95 }, 700);
    return false;
    }}});});
```

Comment: Use `$(document).width()`

Comment: Where exactly to place it mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You need to change:

```
if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 95 }, 700);
```

To:

```
if (target.length) {
    var topPadding= 0;
    if($(window).width() >= 1030)
        topPadding = 95;
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - topPadding }, 700);
```

### Explanation

```
var topPadding= 0; //Sets the default padding to 0 (for when the window is below 1300px)
if($(window).width() >= 1030) //Checks to see if the window width is wider than 1300px
    topPadding = 95; //If it is then set's padding to 95px as in your code above
```

**Note:** that I changed where you have `95` to `topPadding` (where you set `scrollTop`)

Comment: It worked, however - when I resized the window back to over 1030px it actually applied the var topPadding= 0; as well. How can we make it reset and use the 95 when it has been resized to under 1030 and then above - do you know what I mean mate?

Comment: Are you able to come back to the chat?